# Number of columns does not match number of bins

Tags: python, statistics, data-science

I am trying to plot some 336 data points and am encountering an issue with my use of pythons plt.hist() function. I would like to use more than eight bins for my data, but when I do a lot of whitespace is introduced. For example, here is a plot with bins = 8

[image]
and with bins = 24
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9H4N.png]

Does anyone know why this is and how I can best represent my data with more bins? Many thanks, ~S.

Sample code:

```
tumbles = np.array(df['Tumbles'])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1,
                        tight_layout = True)

N, bins, patches = axs.hist(tumbles, bins = 24, edgecolor= "black")

axs.grid(b = True, color ='grey',
        linestyle ='-.', linewidth = 0.5,
        alpha = 0.6)
    
plt.xlabel("Time (s)", size = 14)
plt.ylabel("Frequency", size = 14)
plt.title('Histogram ofTimes', size = 18)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Difficult to answer without the code and data...

Comment: If you don't have any records for .08, there won't be a bar there.

Comment: I have included my code but am unsure of the most efficient way to share data. I have records for 0.08.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like your data is distributed in a way that the empty space between bars are simply bars with height 0 (a lack of samples). In such a case you just don't need more bins.

Please include your code

With this setup I get the same problem:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 9], bins=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello Michiel, I have included my code for you. I am unsure of the best way to share data here. Thank you

Comment: `Print(np.array(df['Tumbles']))` and just show us a screenshot so we can get a clue. 

You have records for 0.08, but also a bar at 0.08. 

If you have no records around 0.22, that would explain why there is no bar there

Comment: You were completely correct, my data is discrete s.t. it goes in intervals 0.04, 0.08, 0.12, 0.16, ... which explains why there is so much regularity in the white space. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bit more effort, but if you want a bit more control over the number of bins and the range of each bin, you might set up the bin parameter in your histogram definition as a list.  This was alluded to above, but here is a snippet of code illustrating that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.27, 0.27, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.044, 0.044, 0.05, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0,10, 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.17, 0,18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.20, 0.22, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0.24, 0.26, 0.26, 0.28, 0.29, 0.30, 0.32]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

N, bins, values = ax.hist(data, [0.000,0.015,0.030,0.045,0.060,0.075,0.090,0.105,0.120,0.135,0.150,0.165,0.180,0.195,0.210,0.225,0.240,0.255,0.270,0.285,0.300,0.315,0.330,0.345], linewidth=1)

plt.bar_label(values)

plt.xlabel("Time (s)", size = 14)
plt.ylabel("Frequency", size = 14)
plt.title('Histogram of Times', size = 18)

plt.show()
```

The data is just a small subset to establish some data points to produce a histogram.  Following was the histogram created in this fashion.

[image: Sample with Bins]

You might give that a try adjusting for the range each bin should have.